# Search query in PostgreSQL using several columns

Tags: postgresql

I have to implement a query search by text but it can match more than one column: address, name, application reference, agent, status or decision.

The row numbers in the database is 1 million and is increasing every week.

This is the table where the query will be executed.

[image]

I was planning on doing queries with "like" statements and some "or" but I don't think that's a good idea for a table that is increasing every week.

Answer (score 0):

I used tsvector to achieve this, this is an example of the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM planning_data JOIN planning_portals ON planning_data.portal = planning_portals.id 
WHERE to_tsvector(
            coalesce(planning_data.title, '') || ' ' || 
            coalesce(planning_data.address, '') || ' ' || 
            coalesce(planning_data.ref_number, '') || ' ' || 
            coalesce(planning_data.status, '') || ' ' || 
            coalesce(planning_data.decision, '') || ' ' || 
            coalesce(planning_data.appeal_decision, '') || ' ' || 
            coalesce(planning_data.applicant_name, '') || ' ' || 
            coalesce(planning_data.agent_name, '') || ' ' || 
            coalesce(planning_data.agent_company_name, '') || ' ' || 
            coalesce(planning_data.agent_address, '') || ' ' || 
            coalesce(planning_data.agent_email, '') || ' ' || 
            coalesce(planning_data.status_group, '') || ' ' || 
            coalesce(planning_data.postcode, '') || ' ' || 
            coalesce(planning_portals.name, '')) @@ to_tsquery('47C & Oldfields & Circus')
```

see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-tables.html

Comment: The cascade of `coalesce()` and `||` could be simplified using `concat_ws(' ', title, address, ref_number, ....)`